# Get youtube trending videos in specific day and region

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The specific information that I want to get is the list of videos that were most viewed in South Korea on Apr 1st, 2020. It would be awesome I can also get the statistics of each videos(such as the number of view counts, likes, dislikes, and comments)
I tried some coding with python using youtube API, but the results seem very different from what I expected. (The title of some videos in the results are written in Arabic or Russian even though their regioncode is KR, I have no idea what's happening.) The followings are my code. Any comments would help. Thx!!

```
api_key=" "

from apiclient.discovery import build

youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey=api_key)

from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime(year=2020, month=4, day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
end_time = datetime(year=2020, month=4, day=2).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

res = youtube.search().list(part='snippet',
                           maxResults='50',
                           regionCode='KR',
                           order='viewCount',
                           type='video',
                           publishedAfter=start_time,
                           publishedBefore=end_time
                           ).execute()

for item in res['items']:
    print(item['snippet']['title'], item['snippet']['publishedAt'])

res
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Search.list` endpoint's [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#regionCode) says that:

> *regionCode* **string**
>
> The regionCode parameter instructs the API to return search results for videos that can be viewed in the specified country. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

This means that filtering a search result set by the `regionCode` being `KR` produces a list of videos that are **allowed** to be viewed in the `KR` region, regardless of the respective videos being actually viewed from within that region or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Then is there any way that I can filter and get the trending videos on that day in South Korea?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no API that accepts all three of your conditions: videos that (1) are most popular, (2) were viewed within a given region and (3) conditions (1) and (2) fulfilled on a specified day. If you can allow yourself to drop the condition (3), you may experiment with the [*Videos.list* endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), calling it with `chart=mostPopular` and `regionCode=KR`. However, I suspect that this endpoint's `regionCode` has the same semantics as the `regionCode` parameter of *Search.list* endpoint (did not tested this myself).